# Symfony2 - identify controller loaded

Tags: php, symfony, controller

In a URL load 2 controllers, one by the route:

```yml
home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:index }
```

another one on twig:

```twig
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:twig')) }}
```

I created a http service, with ***onKernelResponse***, and I would like to identify if controller is loaded by route or by twig.

Any idea to resolve it?

### Edited

I found 2 diferences in headers:

- "accept-charset"
- "x-forwarded-for"

doesn't appear on controller load by route.

perhaps the solution is on this way?

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution

```php
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event) {

    if($event->isMasterRequest()){
        // here my code
    }
}
```